# Using keys to toggle functions in OpenCV- Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am running into thread error :
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7c2d90) is not the object's thread (0xcc44d0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7c2d90)

while trying to run the below program. when i take off the last two lines, it doesn't give me this error. Can anybody tell why this is happening?

```
import sys
import cv2

fileName = sys.argv[1]
print "image read from commandline"

img = cv2.imread(fileName)
print "image sucessfully read"

image = cv2.imread('testimage1.jpg', 0)

cv2.imshow('image', image )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Anaconda package , now i switched to python 2.7 distribution and the error is gone.